# Log sustainsys decrypted assertion

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I'm using HttpModule v1.0.2 in a web form application in .NET 4.

I would like to log the decrypted assertion for debugging purpose, how can I do it?

The SpOptions.Logger log only the EncryptedAssertion.

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I can remember, there is no logging point after decrypting the assertions, nor any notification/callback that can be used for logging.

It's on my list of ideas for the next version, but that will only be available for .NET 6.